# What is an arbitrary object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've been researching google on what it is, but haven't been able to find an answer. You can look up google yourself if you want.

So, I've come here for help. Just wanted to know what that type of object is and what it does.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an arbitrary object in Objective-C (typed `id`), you can inquire information about its class by calling the `class` selector:

```
Class c = [obj class];
```

You can log that to the console (`NSLog(@"%@", [obj class])`) or perform other operations to see which selectors are supported on the object, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's any object that is derived from the language's ur-type (if it has one).